# Seting AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false do not impact on inserting speed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert 10000 rows with EntityFramework 6. To speed up the process i'm disable AutoDetectChanges

```
using (var db = new TestDbContext())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
                db.Adresses.AddRange(adresesModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            }
        }
```

A few days ago this process took ~100 miliseconds, but now it i disable AutoDetectChanges it took ~70000 ms
With enabled AutoDetectChanges it also takes ~70000 ms

I can not find the reason why disable AutoDetectChanges do not impact on inserting speed!

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't try to detect changes on a range, or that process take a negligible amount of time. There are many other reasons why saving to a database takes much longer.

Comment: one of the reason could be you have lot of index on your table (or may be lately you added lot of index on table)....so index rebuilding might add up to this time

Comment: My database is DropCreateAlways and few days ago... as i say before... process took ~100 ms. I didn't change the code or MSSQL settings and now it took ~70000 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why it was taking 100ms few day ago, I believe you was not adding the same amount of entities.

AutoDetectChangesEnabled doesn't work like you think.

**AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true**

- Add: Try to detect change after every record (VERY BAD)
- AddRange: Try to detect changes once every record are added (1 time)
- SaveChanges: Try to detect changes (1 time)

**AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false**

- Add, AddRange & SaveChanges: Doesn't detect changes.

So AutoDetectChanges make almost no difference when using with AddRange. People are used to believe insert will be faster when disabled, but it's only true when used with "Add".

What make a difference is your are inserting 10000 entities, so you doing in fact **10,000 database roundtrip** which is really bad for performance and this is why it take 70000ms to save.

Only BulkInsert library solve this kind of issue:

- https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

  - Free but doesn't support all associations
- [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

  - PAID but support everything

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Comment: Still not found why AutoDetectChanges for me, but efbulkinsert.codeplex.com helped... ~150 ms for 10000 rows. Thanks